# Service worker data with curl

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker

In the Chrome Push notification API, I would like to set a customisable notification.

I am talking about service-worker.

Here is the code of the example service worker.

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) { 
 var data = {};
  if (event.data) {
    data = event.data.json();
  }

    var title = data.message || "Something Has Happened";
  var body = 'We have received a push message !';  
  var icon = '/images/icon-192x192.png';  
  var tag = 'simple-push-demo-notification-tag';

console.log(event);



  event.waitUntil(  
    self.registration.showNotification(title, {  
      body: body,  
      icon: icon,  
      tag: tag  
    })  
  );  
});
```

**How can I catch the data from a curl message with something like this :**

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=---personnal_key---" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"---ID---\"],\"title\":\"ok\"}"
```

I did read the example, but I can't see one talking about the combination of CURL and service worker together.
Is  that even possible ?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question but this excellent article by Matt Gaunt shows how to setup a Push Notification App and how to test it using curl: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2015/03/push-notificatons-on-the-open-web

Comment: I Wonder how to push a message. I guess I should try the fetch function.

Answer (score 1):

In the current iteration of the push notification api you may not send data (see: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2015/03/push-notificatons-on-the-open-web). For now the only way to send specific data is to store it in some database on the server and then have the service-worker fetch it from the server. However, as you would expect this can lead to many security issues. One option is to use the subscription for verification. You can get the subscription id from the service worker like:

```
registration.pushManager.getSubscription().then(function(ps) {
  console.log(ps.subscriptionId)
})
```

Then, assuming how you set up your server, you can make a fetch from the service worker to your server. It might look something like this

```
fetch("/"+subscriptionId+"/getLatest").then(function(res) {
    res.json().then(function(data) {
          self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
          body: data.body,
          icon: data.icon,
          tag: data.tag
        })
    })
})
```

However, all of this requires you to set up an external server. You cannot send data through the cURL request.

Comment: Apparently subscriptionId is being deprecated. Use the data is being encoded into endpoint now

Comment: Do you have more info about this deprecated ?

Comment: You can read about the details of it here https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/m/#!topic/blink-dev/CK13omVO5ds basically they wanted to make it so that endpoint encoded subscriptionId